# Semantic difference between standard SQL and Teradata cast syntax

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to understand the difference between the following two syntaxes, which appear to be doing the same thing when casting strings to integer:

```sql
SELECT CAST('1' AS INTEGER), '1' (INTEGER)
```

Resulting in:

```
|'1'|'1'|
|---|---|
|1  |1  |
```

But they don't do the same thing when chaining the conversion:

```sql
SELECT CAST(CAST('1' AS INTEGER) AS VARCHAR(3)), ('1' (INTEGER)) (VARCHAR(3))
```

I'm now getting:

```
|'1'|'1'|
|---|---|
|1  |   |
```

The second column contains an empty string, not null. Is there a semantic difference between the two syntaxes, or is this just a bug?

I'm using version 16.20.05.01

Comment: For starters, the `'1' (INTEGER)` syntax is not standard SQL whereas `CAST` is, so there's good reason to avoid it, especially since it's easily confused with something like `'1' INTEGER`, which is legal (non-standard) syntax in SQL Server for having a column named `INTEGER` containing the string `'1'`. Even if you never mix T-SQL and Teradata SQL in your project, it's a good idea to avoid short but cryptic constructs like these if there's a standard alternative.

Comment: Thanks, @JeroenMostert, believe it or not, I am very well aware of all of these things ;-) But do you have anything to share that's not "for starters"?

Comment: @JeroenMostert  `'1' INTEGER` is 100% standard SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: well, you learn something new every day. Are the semantics "an expression of type `INTEGER` with value `1`"?

Comment: @LukasEder: I could share [the documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Ri8d7iL59tIPr1FZNKPLMw/PBI~4py9g4ARqYuC0hLweg), which describes the differences between `CAST` and the Teradata syntax for numeric-to-character conversion. This, combined with the default format, appears to explain the results (you're getting the first three blanks of the padded representation).

Comment: @JeroenMostert: That would be the answer right there, thanks! Want to answer my question?

Comment: I would, but I'm having a hard time interpreting the Teradata docs as to what the default format for `INTEGER` (`-(10)9`) actually *means*, in particular, what kind of padding it applies. The documentation on `FORMAT` does a poor job at explaining the grammar. (I have no Teradata instance myself to test against, if that wasn't already clear.)

Comment: Up to you. I'd accept even a link and maybe a quotation of the text on that page... It's documented behaviour which I had overlooked. While I have a Teradata instance, I must have been blind navigating their docs...

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to do this.  Teradata explicitly warns against it.  To demonstrate, try `select '1000' (INTEGER) (varchar(20))`.

Comment: @Andrew: The motivation (which I believe to be irrelevant to the question, but I know, this is SO), is to enhance a SQL parser ([jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org)'s to be specific) that can parse the Teradata conversion syntax. Does that make sense?

Comment: The main difference between legacy Teradata and Standard SQL cast is padding: Standard SQL casts numeric columns left aligned with no padding, but Teradata does it right aligned with leading spaces based on the column's FORMAT. `'-(10)9'` is Cobol-style and means `'----------9'`: exactly 11 characters, with a floating minus sign and at least one digit. In my trainings I usually show automatic casts like yours. Or `select 1 || 1;` :-)

Comment: @dnoeth Does anyone want to provide their comment as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments (no one wanted to answer?), there's documented difference
of behaviour in the section ["How CAST Differs from Teradata Conversion Syntax"](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Ri8d7iL59tIPr1FZNKPLMw/PBI%7E4py9g4ARqYuC0hLweg)

Specifically:

> Using Teradata conversion syntax (that is, not using CAST) for explicit conversion of numeric -to-character data requires caution.
>
> The process is as follows:
>
> 1. Convert the numeric value to a character string using the default or specified FORMAT for the numeric value.
>    Leading and trailing pad characters are not trimmed.
> 2. Extend to the right with pad characters if required, or truncate from the right if required, to conform to the target length specification.
>    If non-pad characters are truncated, no string truncation error is reported.